# Current time in HH:MM:SS am/pm format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I obtain the current time in HH:MM:SS am/pm format?

Comment: Read about `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: I'm unable to figure out how am/pm is displayed in a 12 hr format

Comment: Gory details of format strings: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: **Swift 3 Answer :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/46027060/3400991

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[formatter release];
```

The format of the string in `setDateFormat` is based on ISO-8601, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates

Swift 3 Version:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
print("Current date: \(formatter.string(from: Date()))") // -> Current date: 08:48:48 PM
```

There's also a new site since this original answer that helps writing these format strings. Aptly named... http://nsdateformatter.com

Comment: Maybe add AM/PM indicator as OP requested?

Comment: @martin Can you please elaborate what you mean by 'OP requested' ? Never heard of this before.

Comment: @iPhone - I was pointing out that you asked for the AM/PM indictaor, but Flash84x didn't include it yet.  OP is an abbreviation of "original post" or "original poster". (am/pm is 'a' btw: `"hh:mm:ss a"`.)

Comment: @iPhone Developer, OP means Original Poster, updated to add am/pm

Comment: use HH:mm instead of hh:mm to get the AM/PM

Answer (score 2):

See the [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class and the [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i). Don’t ever do these kind of things by hand, you won’t get the details right.

Answer (score -1):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale: