# NSDateFormatter- stringFromDate not returning AM/PM

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-format

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSLog(@"Today's Time: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

The above code just gives the following output `Today's Time: 15:46:43`
I want the output to be `Today's Time: 3:46 PM`. 
I surfed a lot and i did not find a way to show AM/PM. Would be really helpful if someone can help me find a way out.
I am using XCode 6.3 and my Device has iOS 8.3 installed in it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46027060/3400991 try this in swift 3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Check your device settings for 24 hour time. If it is on, turn it off.**

Your code is perfectly fine. I am getting output as shown below :
Today's Time: 04:31:58 PM

If you don't want to show seconds use this code :

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

Comment: How did i miss it! Thank you. Yes it was my device settings that created the issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 9):

**HH : 24 hour format**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
```

**output**

```
 Today's Time: 16:42 PM
```

**hh : 12 hour format**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

**output**

```
 Today's Time: 04:43 PM
```

Comment: Thank you. `setLocale`  is the key for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]  initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    NSString *stringFromTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the time format of your device time to **12 hour format** instead of **24 hour format**. You can not get am pm in 24 hour time format.

Today's Time: `15`:46:43

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSLog(@"Today's Time: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: Its gives an answer with 24Hr format + AM/PM (`Today's Date and Time: 16:40 PM`) that's absurd.
I want it in a 12Hr format. I tried `@"hh:mm a"` and it just returns `Today's Date and Time: 16:38`

Comment: "HH" it will return time in 24Hr format and "hh" in 12Hr format

Answer (score -1):

You can easily convert Time in 24 hours format .

Try this Code it is working fine for me .

```
        func convertTime(_ dateAsString : String) -> String{
             let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
             dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm:ss " // "h:mm:ss a"
             let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)

             dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
             let date24 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
             print(date24)
             return date24
          }
```

Comment: Why do you have to do 2 conversions for something that can be done in one?