# swift NSDate AM and Pm Format

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

To convert date and time, I have used this:

```
 let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
 formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
 formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
 formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
 formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy, h:mm"
 formatter.AMSymbol = "AM"
 formatter.PMSymbol = "PM"
 let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(model.courseDate)
 print(dateString)
```

If the course date is **"courseDate = "2017-01-09 01:00:00 +0000";"**
 but I am getting like this in print:
**1/09/2017, 1:00** with no any AM or PM.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this `M/dd/yyyy, h:mm a`, and you don't need to set `AMSymbol/PMSymbol`

Comment: Try formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy, h:mm a"

Comment: And it is DateFormatter with Swift 3.

Comment: yes thank you.. How did i missed it..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46027060/3400991 try this

Answer (score 12):

**according to the date formatter specs**

You can retrieve a date in 24h format instead of requesting AM/PM by using
**HH instead of hh**

so  the date "21/11/2016 01:30" (pm)  would be "21/11/2016 13:30".

if you do need to print the format, though, you can print it using:

a

[More date fomatting details here](https://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Answer (score 8):

As per Apple general date formatter you should use "M/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a" in your date format.

**like :** `formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a"`

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

use following code may help full for you

//Call function

```
let dateTime = self.convertDateFormaterAamer(sendTimeStep, inputDateFormate: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", outputDateFormate: "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a")
```

//Date function

```
func convertDateFormater(date: String,inputDateFormate: String , outputDateFormate: String) -> String
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    //dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = inputDateFormate


    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)

    //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MMM EEEE HH:mm"
    //dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = outputDateFormate
    var timeStamp = ""
    if (date != nil)
    {
        timeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
    }
    return timeStamp
}
```