# Notification Wont Send If Time Contains "PM" - swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, localnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I have some code that sends a notification at a certain time every day. The notification works for any time containing am. However, if the time contains pm the notification is not sent. I don't really know why though. Here is my code:

```
static func sendNotification(stringDate: String) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Your daily news is ready!"
        content.body = "Come and check out the latest headlines!"

        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate) {
            let calendar = Calendar.current

            let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
            let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)

            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.hour = hour
            dateComponents.minute = minute

            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "dateDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
```

in the function above I have a parameter called stringDate which is simply a string that contains the time I want to send the notification at. I don't really know the notifications only work in am so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using AM/PM you should use a different date format:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
```

If you don't have control over the input, you could first try to parse it in 24-hour format, and if that doesn't work with the AM/PM format

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you parse the time from string might be wrong, you may get rid of the AM/PM when you parse. I'm not familiar with Swift, so I may be wrong. However, I found this question helpful if that's the problem. [xcode swift am/pm time to 24 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321947/xcode-swift-am-pm-time-to-24-hour-format)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the part where you set the current calendar to the `dateComponents` as Apple examples suggests.

```
dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the full function with usage, if someone get helped.

**Swift 5**

```
func isPM(dateInString: String) -> Bool {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    let dateFromStr = dateFormatter.date(from: dateInString)!
    
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    let timeFromDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromStr)
    return timeFromDate.contains(dateFormatter.pmSymbol)
}
```

Usage:

```
print(isPM(dateInString: "11:40:45")) // false
print(isPM(dateInString: "16:40:45")) // true
```